# Persisting increased playback speed between videos in VLC

Tags: vlc

The playback speed reverts to 1x with every new video in a playlist, however, this isn't the behavior I want. Is there a way to make a selected playback speed persist throughout an entire playlist without re-encoding all the media?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps to get it done.

1. open vlc.
2. in the menu select tools -> preferences
3. Scroll down and select the all button under "Show Settings"
4. Click the "Input/ Codecs" and then scroll down
5. Under "Playback control" set your desired playback speed.
6. Changes would effect immediately (if it doesn't then restart vlc)